# What's differences between "pg_ctl start" and "net start PostgreSQL" in start PostgreSQL Server?

Tags: windows, postgresql

On windows OS, if I have environment variable set, the two commands:

- `pg_ctl start`

And

- `net start PostgreSQL`

seems to do the same thing: Start the postgres server.

So,What is the difference between the two ways of starting the server?

Comment: `net start` is a (general) Windows command to start a Windows service, it is not really related to Postgres in general

Comment: got it,very thanks!